# What can I use in Application that is similar to Activity.onPause()

Tags: android, caching, sharedpreferences, onpause

I am looking for some callback that is similar to Activity.onPause(), but is more general (I don't have an Activity, since this code runs in the background) that is called before my Application is being killed. I din't try Application.onLowMemory() 'cause according to the docs it's not always called [I mean my app could be (and I know sometimes is) killed also when I exit from some activity by back or home button].

I have a LocationListener class in my app that does some pretty heavy calculations, therefore I use some "caching" or optimisation. I only do the heavy calculation when the location has changed quite a bit or enough time passed.

I noticed that most of the time, even when I don't move the phone, my code for the heavy calculations is called again and again. It turned out that it's because the oldLocation is null (my app was killed by android) The app works, because it's being waken up by the LocationService, but it "forgets" the cached lastLocation (=null). So I added saveLastLocation() which indeed helps, but I'm trying to figure out the best place to call it from. At the beginning I called it from finalize(), but it was never called. It seems that android killed my app "too fast" for it to be called. Then I moved it to it's current place, right after the heavy calculation.

I wonder if there's a way, similar to what would be ideal if I was in an Activity where I would use onPause() to call saveLastLocation and onResume to call loadLastLocation.

I hold the instance of MyLocationListener as a static member of MyApplication (for caching purposes)

```
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    private static MyLocationListener instance;
    private Location lastLocation;

    public static MyLocationListener getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new MyLocationListener();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MyLocationListener() {
        loadLastLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        if (null == lastLocation || lastLocation.distanceTo(location) > MIN_LOCATION_CHANGE_DISTANCE
                    || getElapsedNanoSec(location) - getElapsedNanoSec(lastLocation) > MIN_LOCATION_CHANGE_NANOSEC) {
            // Just to see how many times we enter the heavy calculations
            Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), "old: " + lastLocation + "new: " + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // do the heavy calculations

            lastLocation = location;

            // Is there a better way to call saveLastLocation???
            saveLastLocation();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void saveLastLocation() {
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        if (null != lastLocation) {
            editor.putString(PREF_LAST_LOCATION_PROVIDER, lastLocation.getProvider());
            editor.putLong(PREF_LAST_LOCATION_ELAPSED_REALTIME, getElapsedNanoSec(lastLocation));
            putDouble(editor, PREF_LAST_LOCATION_LATITUDE, lastLocation.getLatitude());
            putDouble(editor, PREF_LAST_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, lastLocation.getLongitude());
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void loadLastLocation() {
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        final String provider = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_LAST_LOCATION_PROVIDER, null);
        if (null != provider) {
            final long elapsed = sharedPreferences.getLong(PREF_LAST_LOCATION_ELAPSED_REALTIME, Long.MIN_VALUE);
            final double latitude = getDouble(sharedPreferences, PREF_LAST_LOCATION_LATITUDE, Double.MIN_VALUE);
            final double longitude = getDouble(sharedPreferences, PREF_LAST_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, Double.MIN_VALUE);
            if (null == lastLocation) {
                lastLocation = new Location(provider);
            } else {
                lastLocation.setProvider(provider);
            }
            setElapsedNanoSec(lastLocation, elapsed);
            lastLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
            lastLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
        }
    }

    private long getElapsedNanoSec(final Location location) {
        long elapsed;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            elapsed = location.getElapsedRealtimeNanos();
        } else {
            elapsed = location.getTime() * 1000;
        }
        return elapsed;
    }
}
```

Just to clarify: MyLocationListener is not called straight by google play services, I have another "real" LocationListener that is being called, and from it's onLocationChanged I call MyLocationListener.getInstance().onLocationChanged(location) [the reason I do this is that I use the results of the heavy calculations (by calling other functions not presented here) from many places in my code and I want it to cache as much as possible]

Comment: Does the heavy calculations rely on the old location or do you only use it for determining the distance change?

Comment: It's only used for the optimization, not to do the heavy calculation. The calculation itself only uses the current location (except a log where I print "you moved from <oldLoc> to <newLoc>" but it can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the new [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html) (which replaces the `LocationClient` in Google Play Services 6.5), then you can set a [smallest displacement](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) as part of your `LocationRequest` which will ensure you will only get a callback if the location has changed more than your smallest displacement - this ensures that you will be able to do your heavy calculation each time you receive a callback.

If you really also need to redo the calculation after a certain time, you can set an alarm with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to act as a timeout mechanism on each location update received (and cancel a previously set alarm) which would fire your heavy calculation method if there hasn't been a location update, using [FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) as the current location (or using a cached value if you wish).

Note, `FusedLocationProviderApi` also provides a [requestLocationupdates()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method that takes a `PendingIntent` - this is perfect for background services which don't want or need to maintain a constantly running listener, but want to trigger a short running handler (which an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is perfect for) in response to an event. This ensures that your application will always receive an update even if the app is stopped by Android.

Comment: Actually I already use FusedLocationProvider. Maybe I just need to add smallest displacement and fine-tune the other request parameters.

Comment: Well although I don't use lastLocation in the heavy calculation, but I do cache the "area" (calculated in the heavy part) in order not to send a notification when it's not changed, because some users were disturbed by them, so although your answer did help me, I'm still back to the point where I would prefer to save things only when needed (because my static variables will be killed with the app by android). But maybe I'm just too crazy about "not to write to SharedPreferences" when not necessary, because I'm afraid I'll "kill" the flash memory, and it's ok to save it every time...

Comment: Well if you know every location update is a new location (i.e., beyond the smallest displacement), discounting the alarm timeout. I don't think you'll have a problem of saving things to SharedPreference every minute (while moving) or every timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. Why don't you use the alarm manager to wake up a service periodically (ideally use an inexact alarm) to grab the current location and check if it has changed enough, then inside the service do the heavy calculations  and store the results on a db or a file.

That way you have a more controlled environment for your heavy calculations to run.

You can  also use the new JobScheduler (5+) instead of the alarm manager. If you need a compat version there is a project to bring the JobScheduler back to API 10+ (https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat)

Comment: At the beginning I was thinking about using an inexact alarm (to save battery) but I preferred to use the fused location service, because I need to get a location update if the user is moving fast (let's say in a car he can move 2km/min) in which case it is important to do the heavy calculation, because he might move to a new area within 1 minute, however I don't want to wake up the phone every minute, if he's sitting in his office for 9 hours. Besides even if I did what you suggest I would save the lastLocation every time, which is more or less what I do now.

Comment: You could still use the fused location provider, you could just start location updates from your service and then stop them after a period of time. LocationPoller from CW uses this exact approach: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll